# Laravel change db at runtime

Tags: php, database, laravel

i have an application with one level database for login the users and N databases for one or more users.
i want change the db after a user login.
the db params are stored in the table of the user, so after login i have this:

```
        Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
        "host" => "localhost",
        "driver" => "mysql",
        'default' => 'mysql',
        "database" => $dati->db,
        "username" => "root",
        "password" => ""

    ]);


    DB::reconnect('mysql');
```

where $dati->db is the database name for the logged user.
it work only in the current controller but all the other model and controller don't have the new db and returns error for missing tables.

how can i propagate the new settings to all model?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally having 1 database per user is not recommended.   Unless there is some specific reason for doing this, I would recommend putting all users in 1 database with the relevant access controls needed.

Comment: Hi nigel, abnd thank you for the answare, there is a misunderstanding.
one database with all users inside (permission, levels etc.)
and the every user have a db (two or more user can have the same db).
after login i want to change the db connection (params are in the user's database) for connect the user at his database.

Answer (score 0):

You should put it into a middleware.
For example:

```
<?php
class UserDatabaseMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next){
        $databaseName = $request->user()->db;
        config(['database.connections.mysql.database' => $databaseName]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then you should define it in App\Http\Kernel.php

```
<?php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'dbselect' => UserDatabaseMiddleware::class
]
```

And finally you can add it to your route file. For example:

```
<?php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'dbselect',
], function(){
    Route::get('/', [MyController::class, 'myMethod'])->name('index');
})
```

Now the config should be changed with every http request if user is logged in.

**Important:**
As it was mentioned in the comments - having multiple databases per user is a bad approach. You should consider it.
There is another way to do this - you can have user_id for each record in table and then create global scope to select only records of logged in user.

Comment: hi katsarov, thank you, i'll try this way.
i think i have make a misunderstanding, i have one db at first level with users, roles, permission etc, and N databases for N*N*N... users, one user can login in one database,  obviously some users use the same database.